# VS Code - How to add folders to the search path in a Python project?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, pythonpath

I've recently switched from Spyder to VS Code to code my Python projects. Spyder is great for me because it uses IPython, i.e., it is based on a REPL (interactive environment), but it still lacks some useful features as code refactoring. In turn, VS Code is superb because it provides a more sophisticated editor, but it is hard to configure properly. In my current project, I have this folder structure:

```
\SysID
     |--\src
           |--\app
           |--\core
           |--\utils
           |-- config.py
```

The root of my project (i.e., my workspace) is the folder \SysID and all my runnable scripts are stored within the \app folder. The custom functions I use are stored in the \core and \utils folders, so that I can't import them directly. In Spyder, I had a script (configure.py) to setup the environment, shown below:

```
# config.py 
# This script configures your environment to run all files in this project
import sys, os  

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()),'src','core'))

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()),'src','utils'))
```

Every time I opened the project, I had to run that script first. This solution seems a bit awkward, but it works fine - in Spyder. With VS Code though, it is useless because it opens a new Python session every time you run a script. By researching here and there over the internet (including Stackoverflow) I've tried this:

**(1)** added a cwd key to the launch.json file as below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },        
    ] }
```

**(2)** added the following lines to the settings.json file as below:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${env:PYTHONPATH};
        ${workspaceFolder}/src/core;
        ${workspaceFolder}/src/utils"}
```

**(3)** created a .env file in the root folder of the project with the following text:

```
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH};./src/core # Use path separator ';' on Windows.
```

Nothing worked though. So, folks, what do I have to do to setup the search path of my project as I need? I am using Anaconda to run both Spyder and VS Code.

Comment: If you have ever used pycharm, I guess this is what you need: search **Terminal: Execute In File Dir** in settings.

Comment: *The custom functions I use are stored in the \core and \utils folders, so that I can't import them directly* I am not seeing why you couldn't use imports.

Comment: For reference, documentation from VSCode is here: [use-of-the-pythonpath-variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) Looks like (3) is the recommendation there, but you needed to also add a setting in settings.json so that the `.env` file would be loaded.

Comment: @topsail As far as I am aware, Python imports from subdirectories which are configured as packages. Since .\app, .\utils and .\core are at the same level, trying to import them will raise a "ModuleNotFoundError" exception.

Comment: @topsail I also tried to use an .env file and insert the appropriate key in the settings.json (python.envFile), but it didn't work.

Comment: *Since .\app, .\utils and .\core are at the same level, trying to import them will raise a "ModuleNotFoundError" exception* I'm not sure of the reasoning here. But I just did this yesterday so it seems to me it should work!

Comment: That surprises me! Do you have a reference on that? How would be the syntax for the imports in this case then? I never managed to import modules from "sibling" folders - except by putting them in the Python's search path. If that is possible, why should we set the variable PYTHONPATH or change the settings.json file?

Comment: It so insanely simple so I am just very confused. I very rarely (almost never) set the PYTHONPATH variable or change settings.json for these reasons. To import a sibling I just add the import. Example: create a new folder and open it in VSCode. Create a file called spam.py and a file called eggs.py. Put some simple function in eggs.py. In spam.py add the import `import eggs` and then call your eggs function. That's it. Its the same if you put the files in a folder. Not really sure why you are nesting your app files two levels deep - what's the advantage? Looks kind of Java-ish.

Comment: Sure, but what if spam.py and eggs.py are in folders that are "siblings" (i.e., at the same level)? Say, .\prj\folderA\spam.py and .\prj\folderB\eggs.py?

Comment: Is this the case? You have 5 folders, three levels of nesting. What you are actually trying to import where - spam in eggs, or spam/eggs in app?

Comment: My case here, simplified: I have \prj\app\app1.py, \prj\core\fncTest.py and \prj\utils\fncSupport.py. Script app1.py calls fncTest.py and the latter calls fncSupport.py. How would be the imports in app1.py and fncTest.py without an "unified" search path?

Comment: I would put app in the `prj` folder. I don't see any advantage in putting app.py in nested folder. Then all your problem go away :) Of course you *can* use updates to pythonpath as well .... for sure it works. It seems a little awkward to have to run powershell scripts when you open VSCode though ... this doesn't seem like the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue and will post the answer here as it may help another poor devil trying to solve a similar issue.

The answer turned out to be quite simple. I created a powershell script under the \SysID folder named config.ps1 as:

```
# config.ps1  
$env:PYTHONPATH="$env:PYTHONPATH;$pwd\src\core" 
$env:PYTHONPATH="$env:PYTHONPATH;$pwd\src\utils" 
echo "Your PYTHONPATH variable has been set." 
echo "Its current value is $env:PYTHONPATH"
```

Everything I need to do is run this script in the same terminal VSCODE uses for the Python sessions. In case one resets or kills the terminal, it has to be called again.

Also, in order to prevent the syntax checking feature from telling me my imports are invalid, I added these lines to my settings.json file:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
  "./src/core",
  "./src/utils",
  "./src/app",
  "./"
]
```

All actions I described in my question were completely useless. All that had to be done was to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable by calling the config.ps1 script.